# Will a Transactional Replication break the LSN chain in my backups

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, transactional-replication

I need to create a fairly up to date read only copy of parts of a production database for reporting purposes.

I did look at log shipping to keep the copy up to date but this will break the LSN and render my backups unrestorable (Log backup every 15 minutes).

I reasonable confident that a Transactional Replication will fit the bill working from the Distribution Database and leaving the source unaffected but I can't find a definitive confirmation of this.

Can anybody put my mind at rest (or suggest something better!)

Comment: What do you mean by log shipping will "break the LSN". Can't you just use the same log backups for both purposes?

Comment: I've got "Managed Backups" running every 15 minutes, doesn't the act of shipping the log have the same effect as backing it up? Actually the Transactional Replication seems to be a better solution as I can only copy the parts I need for reporting.

Comment: Could you please add your version / flavour of SQL as a tag? Yes backing up the log is what happens during the shipping process, but there's no reason you can't copy that backed up log file to two separate locations (one for your backup repository, one for the data replication)

Comment: MS SQL Server 2016 Standard running on an Azure Server 2016 - I think I'd have to stop using the "managed backups" and do it the old fashioned way?

Comment: Ah I see - how up to date does the second database ACTUALLY have to be? "Fairly" could mean a lot of different things.

Comment: Managed backups won't play with log shipping, just as you have reasoned. Log shipping has no option to work with where your managed backups are taken. So, either skip your managed backups, or re-think your mechanism for your copy-database. Transactional replication won't break your LSN chain. But I don't encourage repl until you feel confident managing such a setup. Always go for KISS. If log shipping fits your bill, then I think you will be happier with that compared to manage a repl environment.

Comment: Well I started out with a Snapshot Replication taken in the middle of the night as it locks some of the tables when it runs, then they wanted to be able to run reports several time a day, I reckon as long as its within 30-60 minutes it would be acceptable. The Transactional Replication will do the job and allows me to exclude certain tables / columns that aren't required and should be kept secure. As long as it doesn't affect the Transaction Log backups so I can restore to point in time in the event of an accident I'm OK.

Comment: Thanks Tibor, after a lot of trial and error I've got the Transactional Replication working on a couple of test machines (the joys of Azure!) and like I said it has the advantage of being able to select what gets replicated. The production VM hosts several separate Dbs so to replace the managed backups would be a bit of a nightmare. The reporting stuff isn't mission critical so if I've got to rebuild it every now and then it isn't too much of a problem and the database I'm replicating is pretty "mature" so I don't envisage to many structural changes to cause me problem.

Comment: @JohnB You could also restore your full backup + norecovery and afterwards restore your log backups with standby (read only). Kind of a manual log shipping set up where you could restore the logs at set times each day to refresh the reporting db (as users will not be able to report on it while the restore is running).

Answer (score 1):

> I did look at log shipping to keep the copy up to date but this will
>   break the LSN and render my backups unrestorable (Log backup every 15
>   minutes).

Technically, no they won't break the LSN. It simply means when restoring you would have to coordinate restores with both your managed backups and your log shipping backups. While this is a nightmare from a management overhead perspective, it won't actually break your LSN chain like say changing the recovery model would.

> I reasonable confident that a Transactional Replication will fit the
>   bill working from the Distribution Database and leaving the source
>   unaffected but I can't find a definitive confirmation of this.

Transactional Replication reads the transaction log and writes the transactions affecting tables marked for replication into the distribution database for distribution to your subscribers. This does not mark the transaction log except to mark those transactions it has already processed for future runs of the log reader agent to avoid duplication of work.

Transactional replication will not impact your managed backups, break the chain or affect the recoverability of your database from managed backups.